# connect a react-navigation directly to redux?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-navigation

Is it possible to connect a TabNavigator or a StackNavigator directly to redux?

This is very useful for conditionally navigating to a screen, based on whether or not some condition exists in the Redux store (i.e. if the user is signed in or signed out).

Example:

`const Tabs = TabNavigator({
    screen: userIsSignedInRedux ? SignedInTabNavigator : SignedOutScreen,
  },
});`

where userIsSignedInRedux is a key within my Redux store.

Answer (score 0):

It is generally possible, but not recommended, because of the potential performance issues with that approach.

React-navigation had documentation on the topic before but removed it as not recommended in the latest version.

You can check out the following: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/redux-integration.html

You can connect a specific view (first inside a navigator) to redux, and inside the **componentWillMount** method do da redirect if your user is logged in for example.

However, if you have a specific case that would save you time if handled through redux, check out this solution:

https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation-redux-helpers

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import React from 'react';

const TabNavigator = ({ isLoggedIn }) => {
  const RouteConfigs = {
      Screen: isLoggedIn ? SignedInTabNavigator : SignedOutScreen
  };
  const Navigator = createBottomTabNavigator(RouteConfigs);

  return <Navigator />
};

const mapStateToProps = ({ auth }) => ({ isLoggedIn: auth.isLoggedIn });

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(TabNavigator);
```

But make to **not to render your navigation** until the value of `isLoggedIn` is determined .. cause if not, you're going to see a some kind of flickering effect (SignOutScreen will be rendered and a few moments later you're going to see SignInTabNavigator shows up if isLoggedIn resolved to `true`)

Comment: Hey @HendEl-Sahli, I've faced the same issue, I want to hide one tab based on user login state So I make to constant Tab one for user login and another for a gest user So, I'm trying to connect react-navigation route config file to redux store but i can't :\ So I make a class component for handle this stuff but It's wrong way I know, can you check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60302736/how-can-i-access-to-props-inside-react-navigation#comment106706933_60302736) and comments "especially gist File"?