# How can i access to redux store with react navigation?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, react-navigation

I have App "Music App" for tow users type "Guest, a user registered"

I have a bottom navigator for those,
When Guest opens my app I want to render just 4 bottom tabs "Home, browse, search, radio".

but when user login/register I want to render 5 tabs previously tabs plus "Library" Tab.

SO

I dispatch action when user **register\login**, and change isLogin state from *false* to *true* and work some stuff like add some other data to my drawer and it appears fine tho,

I want to access to **redux store** inside react-navigation File "**Tabs.js**",

I want to access state from `mapStateToProps` but I can't access `this.props.isLogin` from non-class component!

So  I don't have any idea how can I do it if i don't use Class component!

So is there a way to access to redux store using "connect HOC" inside Tabs.js file?

Code

**Tabs.js file**

```
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {store} from '../redux/store/store';

const LoginTabs = createBottomTabNavigator({....}); // For user '5 tabs'

const notLoginTabs = createBottomTabNavigator({....}); // For Guest '4 tabs'



const App = this.props.isLogin ? LoginTabs : notLoginTabs; // Not work i know :P

export default (createAppContainer(App));
```

### EDIT For Drew Reese Answer

When I try to do it in this way I got under error message

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  console.log('state', state);
  return {
    isLogin: state.user.isLogin,
  };
};

const App = ({isLogin, ...props}) =>
  isLogin ? <LoginTabs {...props} /> : <NotLoginTabs {...props} />;
const Root = createAppContainer(App);

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Root);
```

Error message

> This navigator has both navigation and container props, so it is
>   unclear if it should own its own state. Remove props: "isLogin,
>   dispatch" if the navigator should get its state from the navigation
>   prop. If the navigator should maintain its own state, do not pass a
>   navigation prop.

## What I tried

I put all Stacks

> "Drawer, Stacks, BottomTabs"

inside One File "Class Component" and it's work but as @Drew say It's not a good idea to do it in this way :)

Here's a [gist](https://gist.github.com/anastely/3c62b98c0cd8d456eed5545270d9e49e) file if you want to see it

Comment: This doesn't look right at all - in the next-to-last line when you're accessing "this.props", you're not inside a component, so "this.props" shouldn't exist.

Comment: @Izkata I know that so my ask is how can i access to `this.props` inside this file :)

Comment: What/where is this new warning our error originating from?

Comment: @DrewReese It's from the Tabs.js file! As you say to change it like this way! Or I miss something?

Comment: @DrewReese If you have time can check this [gist](https://gist.github.com/anastely/3c62b98c0cd8d456eed5545270d9e49e), I know it's too long but it's work after changing it to class pure component and put all stacks in one file!, I think it not a nice way to handle it and hard in refactoring

Comment: I don't think switching to a pure component should really change the component working or not working. Also, nearly all of that logic can (*and should!*) be moved out of the `render` function; you are recreating all your navigators on each render cycle. *This* could be related to the props access issue. That new error message, is there a specific component/element or line number it references?

Comment: Yes, that's the truth... Sadly not referring to the specific line but it appears when I connect this constant (loginTabs/NotLoginTabs) to store to use mapStateToProps, and wrapping it in `createAppContainer(App)` so

Comment: What if instead of trying to connect your redux store there where you're defining your navigators so you can selectively render one or the other of your tabs you move that logic to a "Tabs" component that is connected to your redux store? This is would un-mix the `isLogin` and `dispatch` props being injected by the `connect` HOC. I can update my answer if this works for you. It might even be able to be further reduced as there is a lot of code duplication between your two "tabs" objects.

Comment: @DrewReese hmm interesting, If u have time can u please edit your answer with what u wnat to achieve?

Comment: @DrewReese WE ARE WAITING :3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to create dynamic routes, and one component that renders tabs based on whether the user is logged in or not. in `Tabs.js` do the following.

```
const loginRoutes = {
  Home: {
    screen: Home,
    navigationOptions: {
      title: 'Home',
    },
  },
  Browse: {
    screen: Browse,
    navigationOptions: {
      title: 'Browse',
    },
  },
  Search: {
    screen: Search,
    navigationOptions: {
      title: 'Search',
    },
  },
  Radio: {
    screen: Radio,
    navigationOptions: {
      title: 'Radio',
    },
  },
  Library: {
    screen: Library,
    navigationOptions: {
      title: 'Library',
    },
  },
}

const noLoginRoutes = {
  Home: {
    screen: Home,
    navigationOptions: {
      title: 'Home',
    },
  },
  Browse: {
    screen: Browse,
    navigationOptions: {
      title: 'Browse',
    },
  },
  Search: {
    screen: Search,
    navigationOptions: {
      title: 'Search',
    },
  },
  Radio: {
    screen: Radio,
    navigationOptions: {
      title: 'Radio',
    },
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    isLogin: state.user.isLogin,
 };
};


 const AppNav = ({ isLogin }) => {
  const Container = createAppContainer(
    createDrawerNavigator(
      {
        ...drawerRoutes,
        App: createStackNavigator(
          {
            ...routes,
            Tabs: createBottomTabNavigator(
              isLogin ? loginRoutes : noLoginRoutes
            ),
          },
          routesConfig
        ),
      },
      drawerConfig
    )
  );

  return <Container />;
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(AppNav);
```

[DEMO](https://snack.expo.io/@lekgwaraj/redux-dynamic-routes)

Comment: see my answer here if you get stuck https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56392339/dynamic-route-with-react-navigation?answertab=oldest#tab-top

Comment: My App is running but without Bottom Tabs and I got this warning `Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you return a Component instead of <Component /> from render. Or maybe you meant to call this function rather than return it.`

Comment: add navigation to component like ```const HomeScreen = ({ isLogin, login, logout, navigation }) => {```, see my updated example.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208340/discussion-between-oliver-d-and-junius-l).

Comment: @OliverD This is what I described doing in my last comment in your question.

Comment: @OliverD looks like this answers your initial question, but it seems like you are having issues which were not part of the original question.

Comment: @JuniusL. Hey bro, How r u? if you see this comment, i just stuck on this issue for three days, i need ur help :(,, i just upgrade to r-nav v5 and want to do, two things,  firstly i want to show the bottom tab bar in every nested screen not just in "tabs screens" second .. I can't access to props in function stacks,, please check this [gist](https://gist.github.com/anastely/a644b308ac9997ee30917bd65d4cc2ac) and let me know

Comment: OK I solved this nicely with redux.  I keep a UI section in redux and wire my navigators to this, and can easily control the state from anywhere in the app now.  I jotted it down on medium: https://medium.com/@michaelceber/wrapping-react-navigation-navigators-in-redux-containers-497b432b8911

Answer (score 0):

I think you meant to make `App` a component. In this case it'd be a functional component, so no `this`, and you also need to return valid JSX.

```
const App = props => props.isLogin ? (
    <LoginTabs {...props} />
  ) : (
    <NotLoginTabs {...props} />
  );
```

Notice I've PascalCased the `notLoginTabs` component to be react compliant, and returning them as JSX with `props` spread in.

If the child components don't care about `isLogin` then destructure it out before passing props. This cleans up the code and doesn't pass unnecessary props on to children.

```
const App = ({ isLogin, ...props }) => isLogin ? (
    <LoginTabs {...props} />
  ) : (
    <NotLoginTabs {...props} />
  );
```

**EDIT**

Create a tabs component which houses your authenticated and unauthenticated tabs.

```
const LoginTabs = createBottomTabNavigator( ... );
const NotLoginTabs = createBottomTabNavigator( ... );

const Tabs = ({ isLogin, ...props }) => isLogin ? (
    <LoginTabs {...props} />
  ) : (
    <NotLoginTabs {...props} />
  );

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  isLogin: state.user.isLogin,
});

export default AuthTabs = connect(mapStateToProps)(Tabs)
```

In `AppTest`

```
...
const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator(
  {
    TabHome: {
      screen: AuthTabs,
...
```

Comment: Thank you for a response, I handle my code as you write but i got this error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'undefined' of undefined`

Comment: @OliverD what line of code is being referenced with that error? Where do you try to access an object that has 'undefined' as a property?

Comment: Yes I know what's referred, I just change header title bassed on the bottom tab I pressed so I comment it right now, so these error gone but i got the new one, check please my question again