# How to prevent re-rendering/fetching data in React Class Component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I'm working in a music app using React Native, In the Home Screen I make a class component contains more than four FlatList and it's Get data from API "it's large data",

So i make a function For that, and put it inside componentDidMount(),

But I notice when I log the data after setState I see it **twice Or more** in RN-Debugger

So how can i prevent this happen?
because it's Affected in performance :)

here's a snippet of my code

```
class Home extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: [],
      url: '******',
      loading: false,
      minimal: false,
      MiniURL: '',
      songName: '',
      currentTrackIndex: 0,
      isPlaying: true,
    };
  }
  getRecentSongs = async () => {
    try {
      let response = await API.get('/index');
      let {recent_tracks} = response.data.data;
      let recent_tunes = [];
      recent_tracks.map(track =>
        recent_tunes.push({
          id: track.id,
          name: track.name,
          url: this.state.url + track.sounds,
          img: this.state.url + track.avatar,
        }),
      );
      let data = response.data.data;
      this.setState({data, recent_tunes, loading: true}, () =>
        console.log('data', this.state.data),
      );
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      this.setState({error: true});
    }
  };
  componentDidMount() {
    this.getRecentSongs();
  }



_renderItem = ({item, index}) => {
    const {url} = this.state;
    return (
      <TouchableNativeFeed
        key={item.id}
        onPress={() => {
          this.props.navigation.navigate({
            key: 'Player',
            routeName: 'Player',
            params: {
              tunes: this.state.recent_tunes,
              currentTrackIndex: index,
            },
          });
        }}
        background={TouchableNativeFeedback.Ripple('white')}
        delayPressIn={0}
        useForeground>
        <Card style={styles.card} noShadow={true}>
          <FastImage
            style={{width: 200, height: 200}}
            source={{uri: url + item.avatar}}
            resizeMode={FastImage.resizeMode.cover}
            style={styles.cardImg}
          />
          <Body style={styles.cardItem}>
            <View style={styles.radioCardName}>
              <View style={styles.cardViewFlex}>
                <Text style={styles.text}>{item.name}</Text>
              </View>
            </View>
          </Body>
        </Card>
      </TouchableNativeFeed>
    );
  };

render(){
  const {data} = this.state;

   return(
        ...
        {/* Recent Songs Here*/}
            <View style={{marginVertical: 10}}>
              <FlatList
                horizontal={true}
                showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
                data={data.recent_tracks}
                contentContainerStyle={{flexGrow: 1}}
                ListEmptyComponent={<EmptyList />}
                keyExtractor={(track, index) => track.id.toString()}
                // initialNumToRender={10}
                renderItem={this._renderItem}
              />
            </View>
     ...
  )
 }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell from what's been posted, but is it possible that a key on one of the components is changing more often than you're expecting?  React will trigger a full re-render if it detects any key changes.

Comment: hmm, I think no :\

Answer (score 0):

ComponentDidMount will only be executed once and unmounted when it gets deleted. So that means that it is been created twice in some part of your application.

I have encountered a similar problem and **it was regarding my navigation library**,  in my case, I was using react-navigation https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/2599.

So I can suggest checking if something has happened when your component is created and if it is doing it twice. Also, give a double check if your navigation is not doing the same.

Comment: I think so, can u check these comments" especially my gist to see what I do may be related on what you saying" and main question?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60302736/how-can-i-access-to-props-inside-react-navigation?noredirect=1#comment106685326_60302736

Answer (score 0):

Please use `React.memo`

It will not re-render the component without any relevent data in its props.

eg:

```
/**Your render item*/

const AddsItem = React.memo(({item, index}) => {
   return (
      <TouchableNativeFeed
...
...
</TouchableNativeFeed>
    );
});


/**Your class*/
class Home extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
...
}

render(){
  const {data} = this.state;

   return(
...
...
...
)
}
```

Comment: Same sadly.. maybe here's the problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60302736/how-can-i-access-to-props-inside-react-navigation#comment106685326_60302736